# D3 multi line chart - strange animation

Tags: animation, d3.js, linechart

I have created a multi line chart with a simple animation. In the beginning there are no data and after clicking a button new values are emulated and the line "move" left. The move is animated using a "shift".

The problem occurs when the lines "fill" the whole graph area (that means there are y values for all x values) and then the lines are animated in a different way. It looks like the y values are animated on a curve, not slided to the left.

The animation works good for both axes:

```
svg.selectAll("g .x.axis")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease("linear")
  .call(xAxis);
svg.selectAll("g .y.axis")
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .ease("linear")
  .call(yAxis);
```

And not for lines ([this code](http://bl.ocks.org/benjchristensen/2657838) helped me a lot)

```
svg.selectAll("g .city path")
  .data(processedData).transition().duration(500)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("d", function(d, i) { return line(d.values); })
  .attr("transform", null);
```

The Fiddle is accessible [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QqdYE/10/).

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you a fiddle of the fixed example?

Comment: It was not fixed yet.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're deleting data when there is too much. The way d3 matches data to existing data (when you call the `.data()` function) is by index. That is, the first element in the array that you pass to `.data()` matches the first bound data element, regardless of what the data actually looks like.

What happens in your case is that as soon as you start deleting data, the individual data points are updated instead of shifted. That's why you're seeing the "squiggle" -- it's updating each data point to its new value, which is the value the data point to the right had before.

With the code you currently have, this is hard to fix because you are not matching the data for individual lines explicitly. I would recommend that you have a look at [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) which allow you to draw multiple lines and still explicitly match the data for individual ones. The key is to use the optional second argument to `.data()` to supply a function that tells it how to match the data (see [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data)). This way you can tell it that some data points disappeared and the other ones should be shifted.

Comment: Part 2 of this bar chart tutorial will also help: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Comment: Thanks for comments, but it's not clear to. The bar chart is easy to understand, because there's only 1 set of data and the difference between data for bar chart and line chart is large - isovlated values vs. array of values). Lars, can you help me with the nested selection?

Comment: The idea is that you call `.selectAll().data()` twice -- the first time for a line and the second time for the data points. So in the first call you pass in a matrix where every row contains the points for a line. Then, based on this data you make a second selection for the actual paths and add the path elements. This is explained in more detail in the tutorial I've linked to -- think of the table rows as lines and the table cells as data points of individual lines.

Answer (score 2):

you can get around this problem in 2 step.

in **function update()** : redraw you **.data()** with the new point at the end but without remove the first old point (with animation), like that each key is the same before and after transition.

at the end of **function update()** : you can remove the old value and redraw **.data()** without animation.